# How to set 100% height body in Angular application?

Tags: angular

**My CSS properties:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

**Structure of components:**

```
<body>
   <app-root>
       <app-form></app-form>
   </app-root>
</body>
```

By default body is 100% of viewport height, but when I scroll page body is not stretched to full height including viewport.

So. I need to set height body including viewport, that body fills full height

Comment: "page" refers to what ?  do you mean `web page`? why do you expect body to stretch as height is given 100%; It means it will take the height of the viewport.

Comment: Please ask your question with more details, It seems html body having 100% of viewport height then what is the issue here?

Comment: I have updated my question with details

Comment: `app-root, app-form {  display: block; height: 100%;  }` should work for your case

Comment: Not working for me, body has still height of viewport, not with scroll

Comment: Can you please reproduce your issue in stackblitz? It would be easier for us to understand your goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue:

```
html,
body {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
}
```